# After concatenating files console gives: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp

I've task in my gulpfile, that concatenating all my js files in some order. But after concatenating and reloading page, console writes that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
```

Here is my task:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src([
    'source/components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'source/components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js',
    'source/components/easing/easing-min.js',
    'source/components/hoverintent/dist/hoverintent.min.js',
    'source/components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'source/components/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js',
    'source/components/jquery.uniform/src/js/jquery.uniform.js',
    'source/components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js',
    'source/components/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
    'source/components/jquery-cacheimage/jquery.cacheimage.js',
    'source/components/moment/min/moment.min.js',
    'source/components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js',
    'source/scripts/main.js'
  ])
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(concat('main.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('scripts/js'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
});
```

Comment: does it work when you don't uglify?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Where is error..in browser or node console?

Comment: Error is in browser